# Is the Dedekind zeta function always non-vanishing at $s=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

Is the Dedekind zeta function of a number field always non-zero at $s=\frac{1}{2}$? For Riemann zeta function, it's true by direct computation. If this is true for quadratic fields, then one can use this to prove that the root number of Dirichlet L function of any quadratic Dirichlet character is $1$ (Indeed it's $1$ from other approachs).

Answer (score 4):

Examples were given by Armitage in his paper "Zeta functions with a zero at
$s=\frac12$" in *Inventiones Mathematicae* vol. 15, pp. 199-205, 1971.

Comment: Thank you! I don't notice that paper before, do we know the non-vanishing for quadratic fields?

Comment: So they say if the sign of the functional equation of $\Lambda(s,\pi), \pi = \tilde{\pi}$ is $-1$ then it has a zero of odd (possible negative) order at $1/2$, then they relate that sign to algebraic properties (conductor, ramification) of some Artin L-functions. @zzy You are supposed to share your efforts and knowledge, otherwise MSE is useless.

Comment: @reuns OK, I will add some details about how I come across this problem.